# wdullaer Datetime picker library causes support library different versions error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, datetimepicker

I have a problem with my dependencies and I do not know how to fix it. I am not well versed on the inner works of Android Studio itself.

it is involved with this:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

I needed a date time picker and I used this(https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker), instruction just says copy to dependency so I did.

I copied

```
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.1'
```

and synced it as usual,

then this happened

`All com.android.support libraries must have the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 27.0.2, 26.1.0. Examples include com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2 and com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0`

I do not know how this happens since last time I encountered this is when I added

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
```

and it was of the different version with AppCompat so changing the version fixed it.
So I tried fixing it by adding

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
```

Since it was the one on the error message but it did not do anything.
I am confused since I have not added anything with `implementation`

This might not sound cohesive but I hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

`com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.5.1` uses support library v 27.0.2

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker/blob/master/library/build.gradle

You need to use the same support library version. Replace all occurrences of `26.1.0` with `27.0.2`